# Webview is not opening the new intent

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a application that uses webview in order to load a page. In this page i have some link that i need to open them with another intent with an application called MX Player for video playing. But the problem is that my webview even if i click in a link that doesn't ends with mp4 or a link that ends with mp4 it does nothing. 
Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.loadUrl("LINK OF MY PAGE");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            url = webView.getUrl();
            if (url.endsWith(".m3u8") || url.endsWith(".ts") || url.endsWith(".amv") || url.endsWith(".mp4"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
                intent.setDataAndType( videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL" );
                intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad" );
                startActivity( intent );
            }
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: don't do `url = webView.getUrl();`. You already have `String url` as method parameter

Comment: I removed the url = webView.getUrl() now the problem is the files that doesnt end with mp4 they open with the webpage intent:plus the link What to do?

Comment: then what those files end with?

Comment: with html, is there any declaration to make all other files to be opened in the same webview?

Comment: ok, you probably need to remove `webView.loadUrl(url);` and also probably return false instead of true

Comment: Yes now its working. But now it has another problem when i open a file with the external media player with mx player it opens it but when i click back to get back to the app there is another media player opened in my app. What to do?

Comment: you need another `return true` inside `if(){... return true;}`

Comment: Where should i put it I didn't get it sorry?

Comment: ok let me post a full answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` should return

> true if the host application wants to leave the current
>   WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

This means that your overriden `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` should return `true` if you want to handle the URL by yourself, and `false` if you don't want to handle the URL, and WebView should open it. So your code should look like this:

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        //url = webView.getUrl(); --remove this. You already have the URL in String url parameter
        if (url.endsWith(".m3u8") || url.endsWith(".ts") || url.endsWith(".amv") || url.endsWith(".mp4"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
            intent.setDataAndType( videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL" );
            intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad" );
            startActivity( intent );
            return true; // to tell the WebView that it should not load the URL because you handled it by yourself
        }
        //webView.loadUrl(url);  remove this. You need to return true or false to tell the WebView if it should load the url, or not
        return false; //to tell WebView that you didn't handle the URL, and it should load it.
    }
```

Comment: Still the problem with the video player in the webview exists. With the return true in the end the webpages doesn't load

Comment: @Emiljan, I thought that it is what you want - not load the page if there is a video in it

Comment: No i wanted to play the video in the external app not in the same webview, how to stop creating that new video player in the webview?

Comment: and now the video is played in both - external player and webview?

Comment: Yes the both are opening

Comment: @Emiljan you can try make webView bo back one step before returning true.  Probably it will help